# difference between order by and sort by in sql (databricks)

Tags: sql, databricks

I think there is no difference.

```
    select *
           from new_payrollmaster
           where new_salary > 30000
           order by new_salary desc
```

Comment: idk the answer but this seems like something you can test

Comment: `Sort By`: Impose ordering on a set of expressions within each partition. If not partitioned, there should be no difference

Answer (score 0):

In databricks:

**ORDER BY**

Impose total ordering on a set of expressions. Default sort direction is ascending. You cannot use this with SORT BY, CLUSTER BY, or DISTRIBUTE BY.

**SORT BY**

Impose ordering on a set of expressions within each partition. Default sort direction is ascending. You cannot use this with ORDER BY or CLUSTER BY.

Reference: [Databricks for SQL developers  SQL reference  Select](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/select.html)

Hope this helps.